# In VSCode + Go, is there any way to run a custom script for "Run Test"/"Debug Test"?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm currently porting a project from Python to Go. I have test code that needs some external scripts for initialization (i.e. it needs access to passwords that are stored in 1Password, I need to make sure that the docker postgres image is setup, etc.) There are a few things that I can change, but most of the project is constrained by the existing infrastructure.

In VSCode, I'd like to be able to click on "Run Test"/"Debug Test" to run the tests.

1. Is there any way to get "Run Test"/"Debug Test" to run a custom script instead of `go build`?
2. Alternatively, is there any way to convince `go build` to run a custom script when I'm running tests?

Comment: Look into launch.json configurations for vscode Just Google "vscode launch.json"

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope, you mean these "run test" buttons whic VSCode inserts before each test. No, there is no way to change command, but there is a way to change it's parameters and environment. Take a look to these parameters for settings.json:

```
    "go.testEnvVars": {
        "MY_VAR": "test"
    },
    "go.testTimeout": "2m",
    "go.testFlags": [
        "--count=1"
    ]
```

2. I do not understand your intention. Generally speaking, we use shell scripts to run `go`, but not `go` to run shell scripts. But there are few ideas. 
   First, see the `go generate` command - it runs scripts defined in the source code. 
   Second - `go run main.go` when main.go contains `exec.Command()`

Comment: 1. Yes, I've been doing that.